# Android: onClickListener fires a observer to update field on UI, again and again

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I have a question.
This is my situation.

I have a UI to update values on an Data Object (room data).

Let's say that is a radio Button, but could be anything.

I want that every time the user click on a field (radio button, text, checkbox) the database get updated, I don't want a "save" button.

To achieve this, I have a bunch of onClicklistener() on each view element.

These listeners call some method on the viewmodel instance, that updated the MutableLiveData of that class, firing, the observer on the activity.

The observer in the activity, detects the change in the data class, and assign again the value to the radio button... firing the event in onClickListener ... again.

I could overcome this by assigning "null" to each listener, just before the assignment of the new value.
And then restoring the listener ...

But I feel this is not the best way.

Can someone give some ideas ?

some code.. (viewModel)

```
    private var _fc = state.getLiveData<FilialCruza>("FilialCruza").also(::println)
    val fc : LiveData<FilialCruza> get() = _fc
    ...

    fun onSetPv(value: Int) {
        val fc = _fc.value?: null
        fc.let {
            it?.pv = value
        }
        _fc.postValue(fc)
        setSyncroSts()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            filialCruzaRepository.update(fc!!)  //Insert con OnConflictStrategy = replace
            _modificado.value = false
        }
    }
```

.. Fragment ..

```
           binding.apply {
                fcRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)

                fcRadioGroup.clearCheck()
                fcRadioGroup.check(-1)
                when (it?.pv) {
                    1 -> fcRadioGroup.check(fcRadioGroup.getChildAt(0).id)
                    2 -> fcRadioGroup.check(fcRadioGroup.getChildAt(1).id)
                    3 -> fcRadioGroup.check(fcRadioGroup.getChildAt(2).id)
                    4 -> fcRadioGroup.check(fcRadioGroup.getChildAt(3).id)
                }
    ...

                //PV
                fcRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
                    if (checkedId > 0) {
                        val radio: RadioButton = group.findViewById(checkedId)
               ...

                      if (radio.isChecked) {
                            when (checkedId) {
                                R.id.rb_pv_1 -> {
                                    viewModel.onSetPv(1)   //Call method in ViewModel !
                                }
               ...
```

Comment: May be try like this: Take the triggered button reference on top of your class.. check in the observer if it's matching don't update it.. Caution: incase error happening your sending against state the loop will occur again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually using an `OnClickListener`, you're using an `OnCheckedChangeListener` - that's important because programmatically setting the value of something doesn't trigger a **click**, but it *does* trigger a **change**.

You'll often just want to use **click** listeners, check the `View`'s state inside the listener if you need to (but you probably don't if the `ViewModel` is the source of truth for the current state), and fire off the event/update to your VM. When the VM's state changes and your observer fires, it can just set the `View`'s state without triggering another event.

This kinda makes sense - if the UI is just pushing events and the VM is responsible for holding and pushing the current UI state, you don't really need a `CheckedChange` listener. That's something that involves logic about what the previous and current state is, and worrying about that might be the VM's job - just registering clicks might be all you need!

---

That said, there are some widgets that don't really work on clicks, like `Slider`s, and you might need a different kind of listener for those. [Some of them are helpful about that though](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/slider/Slider.OnChangeListener#onValueChange(com.google.android.material.slider.Slider,%20float,%20boolean)):

> **Slider.OnChangeListener**
>
> `public abstract void onValueChange(Slider slider, float value, boolean fromUser)`

This one has that `fromUser` boolean, which is *true* if the change came from a user interaction with the widget, and *false* if it was updated some other way. So you'll want to check that, and only send an event to the VM if it's a user interaction - if it's not, you're probably seeing it in response to an update pushed by the VM, so you obviously don't want to push another event and create a loop!

So yeah, if you need anything more than a click listener, check what's available in the listeners you *do* have. And if you need to, you could do something similar yourself - have an `updating` flag that you set whenever you're handling a UI state update pushed by the VM. Any listeners could check that when deciding whether to fire an event, and just not bother if an update is taking place. Unset it at the end of the update process, and then any changes that happen while it's *false* must be down to the user (unless it's the UI widgets restoring their state, but that's another story!)